# Where does the 'custom' field show up in coinbase notifications APIv2?

Tags: api, notifications, coinbase-api

While setting up a site to use a Coinbase payment button, I'm trying to figure out where in coinbase API v2 Order notifications the 'custom' field shows up.  In [API v1](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v1#orders), it was in `notification['orders'][0..n]['order']['custom']`, but I can't find where it is in [API v2](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#orders).  Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the field is now `'metadata`.

Here's an example order notification:

```
{
  "id": "b84f7aba-487f-5487-9885-b69953d8d077",
  "type": "wallet:orders:paid",
  "data": {
    "resource": {
      "metadata": {
        "meta": "data",
        "dat": "a meta"
      },...
```

Whereas v1 allows you to add a single custom parameter, v2 will allow you to include key value pairs as outlined in the [v2 Metadata documentation](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#metadata).

Edit to address the comment:

In v1, the `custom` parameter could be included in the URL parameters for a given button, which meant the same button could be reused, as long as the name, price, description, etc., didn't change.

In v2, the `metadata` parameter must be included in the body of the [checkout request](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#create-checkout). This means that in order to attach unique metadata to an order, a unique checkout (button) will need to be created for each potential customer.

Comment: so the above could be the result of a request to a button API button with `?meta=data&dat=a%20meta` ?

Comment: So no more static checkout requests?  I'm wanting to use a `<form method=GET action="http://coinbase.com/..."><textarea name="custom"></textarea></form>` on a static page to place orders.